# Add break in footnote gt table

Tags: r, break, gt

I would like to add some breaks in the footnote of a [gt](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_footnote.html) table. When I add `\n` or `<br>` it doesn't work. Here is some reproducible code from the link:

```
library(gt)
sza %>%
  dplyr::filter(
    latitude == 20 &
      month == "jan" &
      !is.na(sza)
  ) %>%
  dplyr::select(-latitude, -month) %>%
  gt() %>%
  data_color(
    columns = sza,
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c("white", "yellow", "navyblue"),
      domain = c(0, 90)
    )
  ) %>%
  tab_footnote(
    footnote = "Color indicates height of sun. \n 
    I would like to have a break here",
    locations = cells_column_labels(
      columns = sza
    )
  )
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see there is no break in the footnote. I also tried to add `fmt_markdown(columns = everything())`, but that also doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add a newline in the footnote of a `gt` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the HTML `<br>` tag to insert newline worked for me, but you have to also use the `html` function.

```r
library(gt)

sza %>%
  dplyr::filter(
    latitude == 20 &
      month == "jan" &
      !is.na(sza)
  ) %>%
  dplyr::select(-latitude, -month) %>%
  gt() %>%
  data_color(
    columns = sza,
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c("white", "yellow", "navyblue"),
      domain = c(0, 90)
    )
  ) %>%
  tab_footnote(
    footnote = html("Color indicates height of sun. <br> 
    I would like to have a break here"),
    locations = cells_column_labels(
      columns = sza
    )
  )
```

[image: gt_table]